# If dialog.result.Cancel then do something

Tags: vb.net

Below is my code. Whenever a user clicks cancel in the savedialog.showdialog() screen it still tries to save the zip file any help is appreciated!

Thanks,

Kyvex

```
        If saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel Then
            Return
        Else
            zip.Save(zippath)
        End If
```

Comment: Call `ShowDialog` and assign the result to a variable and then compare that variable in the `If` statement. That way, you can use the debugger to actually look at the value. Presumably it is not `Cancel` but that will confirm it.

Comment: Why do you have such a silly `If...Else` anyway? Why not just test for `OK` and then you can get rid of the `Return` and the `Else`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney The OP may have reduced the code to the MCVE, as encouraged.

Comment: @AndrewMorton, fair point.

Answer (score 0):

Could try something like this? If its just a simple yes/no/cancel box?

```
 Dim result As Integer = MessageBox.Show("message", "caption", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel)
    If result = DialogResult.Cancel Then
        *whatever you want
    ElseIf result = DialogResult.No Then
        *whatever you want
    ElseIf result = DialogResult.Yes Then
        *whatever you want
    End If
```

*just seen it was a savefiledialog* in that case do soemthing similar to this

```
If SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.Ok
    zip.Save(zippath)
Else
    msgbox.show("Cancelled!")
End If
```

or another option may be

```
Select Case SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
    Case DialogResult.Ok
        zip.Save(zippath)
    Case DialogResult.Cancel
        msgbox.show("Cancelled!")
End Select
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the DialogResult.OK is more effective, because you will only write the file if you click "OK"

```
If SaveFileDialog.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
    zip.Save(zippath)
Else
    Return 
End If
```

There are a few ways to cancel the save of the file, and in some of them, the dialog result is not "Cancel".

Comment: What is it, then? Do you have a practical example where you close a SaveFileDialog without choosing `Save` and the result is not `DialogResult.Cancel`?

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate all the help! But I did find the fix. What I did was set a variable to the saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() like so

```
Dim tempvar = saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
```

Then I set a break point for when the DialogResult happens. When the user clicks cancel or the X in the top right corner it sets tempvar to false but if they click Save it sets it to true so below is the code I made up, and it works great!

```
If tempvar = False Then
    Return
Else
    zip.Save(zippath)
End If
```

I appreciate all the help guys! Thank you very much!